# Adding fixed time onto datetime gives unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a query that takes two datetime variables (Start date and end date) and appends two differing fixed times to allow for a business trading time offset.

An example of a test query using this logic is:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime;
DECLARE @enddate datetime;

SET @startdate = convert(datetime,'2017-01-01')
SET @enddate = convert(datetime,'2017-01-02')


SELECT  *
FROM ig_Business..Check_Item_Detail CID (NOLOCK)
JOIN ig_business..Check_Sales_Detail CSD (NOLOCK) ON CSD.transaction_data_id = CID.transaction_data_id
WHERE csd.tendered_date_time BETWEEN DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, convert(date, @STARTDATE)), 0) + '06:00:00' 
AND DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, convert(date, @ENDDATE)), 0) + '05:59:59'
```

However, the result set for this query is empty, and I am unsure why, because when I run

```
select DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, convert(date, @STARTDATE)), 0) + '06:00:00'
```

i get back a seemingly valid datetime : 2017-01-01 06:00:00.000

An example of what is returned when I remove the time restriction:
[image]

Comment: The result of `SELECT DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, '', convert(date, @ENDDATE)), 0) + '05:59:59' ` yields `2017-01-01 05:59:59.000`. Note the date is not what you might expect.

Comment: What do you expect your start and end range to be after the calculation? It's not clear from the code if you mean to be doing minutes or months (please [don't use lazy shorthand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/) - if you mean MONTH, **type MONTH**). So given input of January 1 and January 2, you want the query to search for rows where tendered date/time is >= January 1 at 6 AM and <= January, uh, 2nd and 5:59 AM? Another tip: stop using BETWEEN. Much easier to calculate >= 6 AM and < the next 6 AM. That's covered in the link above too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i get back a seemingly valid datetime : 2017-01-01 06:00:00.000

You're not.

You're getting back a date that has been automatically cast to a string, and have glued another string on the end, giving you a string that *looks like* a datetime.

If you want to add something to the date, use another dateadd(). This will give you a BETWEEN comparison with actual datetimes.

Right now you are doing a "between" with a datetime and a string.

I'm surprised it doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

If 2012+, you can use `format()` to append a time to a date/datetime value

**Example**

```
Declare @startdate date = '2017-01-01'
Select format(@startdate,'yyyy-MM-dd 06:00:00')
```

**Returns**

```
2017-01-01 06:00:00
```

This `format()` can be included in your where

```
...
Where SomeDateTime between format(@startdate,'yyyy-MM-dd 06:00:00') 
                       and format(@enddate,'yyyy-MM-dd 17:00:00')
```